# Update bundle data of tabs frgament onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

i can't solve this problem.

I have one activity : PdvActivity with a viewPager.
This activity gets a list of data and set this data to the TabsPagerAdapter.
TabsPagerAdapter create 3 tabs fragments and pass the data in their bundle.
The first tab has a gridView with items from the list he received from the bundle.
I click on an item and an activity start ... when activity finish i need to refresh this grid.

I did :

PdvActivity onResume : i read the fresh data, i set the data in the adapter and i set again the adapter to the pager

```
Panel[] panels = DB.getPdvPanels(pdv.id, true, activity_list);
Company company = DB.getCompany(panels[0].attivita.company_id);
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mAdapter.setPdv(pdv);
mAdapter.setActivities(panels);
mAdapter.setCompany(company);
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In the first Tab onResume :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Panel[] array_panel = (Panel[])getArguments().getParcelableArray("attivita");
    gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AttivitaPdvAdapter(getActivity(), array_panel));
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}
```

PdvActivity gets the fresh data, but the grid refresh itself with old data from bundle. And nothing change.

What i am missing ?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to update the bundle.
So i changed my code in a way that i think is a workaround.

Instead of refresh data in the main activity i moved that piece into the fragment.
Now in the bundle i pass only the arguments needed to do the query and i instantiate the DB inside the fragment to do the query.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Panel[] array_panel =   (Panel[])getArguments().getParcelableArray("attivita");
    gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AttivitaPdvAdapter(getActivity(), array_panel));
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}
```

to that :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ArrayList<Attivita> activity_list = (ArrayList<Attivita>)getArguments().get("attivita");
    panels = DB.getPdvPanels(pdv.id, true, activity_list);
    gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new AttivitaPdvAdapter(getActivity(), panels));
    gridview.invalidateViews();
}
```

I dont know if is a good solution, or if there is a better way. 
But it works, and it seems ok for me.

Hope it will helps you.